# busybox/node.js giving ELF syntax error when ran under Kubernetes

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, busybox

My node.js kubernetes dev server is stuck in a crash loop. The logs show:

```
/bin/busybox:1
ELF
^
SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:992:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:941:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:16)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
stream closed
```

I found the image that's running via `kubectl describe` and ran it in a shell. It ought to be running this (from the `Dockerfile`):

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "--max-old-space-size=4096", "--enable-source-maps"]
CMD ['node_modules/.bin/rollup','-cw']
```

So in the shell I ran:

```
❯ dsh myregistry/project/server:R4SUGQt
+dsh:1> docker run --rm -it --entrypoint sh myregistry/project/server:R4SUGQt -c '{ command -v zsh && exec zsh -il ;} || { command -v bash && bash -il ;} || { command -v ash && ash -il ;}'
/bin/ash
06884c20d5cc:/app# node --max-old-space-size=4096 --enable-source-maps node_modules/.bin/rollup -cw
```

And it works perfectly. So where's that error stemming from? All the paths in the stack trace internal (`internal/modules/...`) not from my script or rollup.

I'm using `node:alpine` as my base image which is currently on Node v14.11.0.

---

Running it directly

```
docker run --rm myregistry/project/server:R4SUGQ
```

**does** reproduce the error.

---

Running

```
docker run -it myregistry/project/server:R4SUGQt node_modules/.bin/rollup -cw
```

Works fine... is there something wrong with my `CMD` syntax?

```
CMD ['node_modules/.bin/rollup','-cw']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the single quotes I used in the `CMD`.

Found this reddit post after the fact: https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/9wn5gw/be_aware_of_the_quotes_in_your_dockerfile/

What a waste of time... leaving this question here in case someone else hits a similar error, maybe it'll be Googlable for them.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while running pm2 in cluster mode.

To fix it, I just changed the `script` field in the `ecosystem.config.json` file from `"script": "node src/index.js"` (this one works when not using cluster mode) to `"script": "src/index.js"`.